# Turn off an iOS device connected to a USB port

Tags: java, ios

So, I want to be able to detect and shut off (shut down), or reboot a iOS device in a java program. Is there any way I can be able to shut a iDevice down in a java program while its connected via a USB port?
Here is what the "code" might look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
iosshutdown.forceReboot()
}
```

Any way I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: `magic.cantBeWilledToExist()`.

Comment: `try { Apple.allowUsersToActuallyUseIDevicesHowTheyLike(); } catch (AppleWontDoThatException e) { /* expected */ }`